# how to store a bitmap into internal storage in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, file-handling

I know it's a very basic question but i am stuck to resolve this problem. I am working on image-sketching mobile app i have done all the work now I just want to store a resulting bitmap-image into internal memory.I have created a method "mageStore()" for image-storing purposes please write code there. I will be very thankful to you.

```
`private class ImageProcessingTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ProgressDialog abhanDialog = null;
    private Bitmap returnedBitmap = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        returnedBitmap = null;
        abhanDialog = new ProgressDialog(AbhanActivity.this);
        abhanDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.please_wait));
        abhanDialog.setCancelable(false);
        abhanDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        final Bitmap sketched = AbhanSketch.createSketch(params[0]);
        final Bitmap gaussianBitmap = AbhanEffects.applyGaussianBlur(sketched);
        final Bitmap sepiaBitmap = AbhanEffects.sepiaTonnedBitmap(gaussianBitmap, 151, 0.71,
                0.71, 0.76);
        returnedBitmap = AbhanEffects.sharpenBitmap(sepiaBitmap, 0.81);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (abhanDialog != null && abhanDialog.isShowing()) {
            abhanDialog.cancel();
        }
        if (result != null) {
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            mImageView.buildDrawingCache();
            bmap = mImageView.getDrawingCache();
            storeImage(bmap);
            isImage = false;
            enableButton();
            final boolean isFileDeleted = Utils.deleteFile(mPath);
            if (DEBUG) {
                android.util.Log.i(TAG, "File Deleted: " + isFileDeleted);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {
    ...please enter code here for image storing
}`
```

Comment: File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
  if (pictureFile == null) {
   Log.d(TAG,
     "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
   return;
  }
  try {
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
   image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
   Toast.makeText(AbhanActivity.this, "stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   fos.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
  } catch (IOException e) {
   Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
  }

Comment: i am using the above code for image storing purposes

Comment: refer my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967711/how-to-take-screenshot-for-android-surface-view/37968834#37968834 , you have to render parent view in which your image view reside and take it as screenshots ,rest of the things are mention there.

Comment: `storeImage(bmap);` ??? Why not storing the original bitmap? Like `storeImage(result);` ?

Comment: Do you want to store the bitmaps pixels/bytes or create a jpg or png or what?

Answer (score 0):

in your function write the following code

```
String path = Saveme(image,"image_name.jpg");
//path contains the full path to directory where all your images get stored internaly lolz but privately

for gallery
 Saveme(image,"my image","my image test for gallery save");
```

and the defination for the Saveme() function is following

```
private String Saveme(Bitmap bitmapImage, String img_name){
            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
             // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
            File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            // Create imageDir
            File mypath=new File(directory,img_name);

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {           
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
           // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
                bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                  fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
            return directory.getAbsolutePath();
        }
```

in gallery images are displayed from media store so you need to store image in media store the following code can help you for this

```
public void Saveme(Bitmap b, String title, String dsc) 
{
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, title ,dsc);    
}
```

Comment: i have tried this method but not find any resulting image.. i  have no sdcard just internal memory.

Comment: If you please let me know that "how we will save the image into the gallery"

Comment: this method is storing image privately so that only your application can access it so see my edited answer

Comment: if it is then why dont you accept it as answer and up vote it :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is your missing code inside a function

```
private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {

    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ;

    File folder = new File(sdcard.getAbsoluteFile(), "YOUR_APP_DIRECTORY");
    if(!folder.exists())
        folder.mkdir();
    File file = new File(folder.getAbsoluteFile(), "IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg") ;
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 400, (int) ( bitmap.getHeight() * (400.0 / bitmap.getWidth()) ) ,false);

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can omit or edit this line

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 400, (int) ( bitmap.getHeight() * (400.0 / bitmap.getWidth()) ) ,false);
```

according to your need.